# How to get a list of files in a directory sorted as from latest to earliest without getting FileNotFoundError exception for broken links in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have directory full of files and sym links.
Amongst that few sym links could be broken meaning the file it is pointing to might be deleted.

I want to list all files in reverse chronological order (from latest to earliest)
But, I am getting FileNotFoundError as getmtime fails. 
How can I avoid getting that FileNotFoundError and get the list for all available files.

Below is my code :

```
import glob
import os

for file_name in max(glob.iglob("*release*.log"), key = os.path.getmtime):
    print ("filename = {}".format(file_name))
```

Even if I use try-except , the program stops at when it is getting the broken sym link.
How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you use `max`, instead of `sorted`, if you want to get all files in  chronological order.

Comment: You can change `key=os.path.gmtime` to a wrapper function, that does exactly the same, but has a `try`-`except FileNotFoundError` around the `os.path.gmtime(fname)` call. You should then return a default value for non-existing files, so that they get sorted at the top or bottom.

Comment: I want in reverse chronological order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter files first, with `filter` and `os.path.exists`:

```
import glob
import os

for fname in sorted(
                 filter(os.path.exists, glob.iglob("*release*.log")), 
                 key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True):
    print(f"filename = {fname}")
```

(I have used `sorted`, since you mention you want to sort the files; `max()` returns a single item, which you can't iterate over, so your example wouldn't work even with non-broken links (albeit that you can in fact iterate over a single filename, but the result is probably not what you want: one filename character at a time).)

Comment: It is working but it is giving in sorted order meaning earliest to latest. I want from latest to earliest. Thanks

Comment: I used reverse = True to the sorted function to make it work!

Comment: I've added `reverse=True` for completeness; that's the (very) easy bit.